# Configuring the Batch Configurer to include transaction with Spring Data MongoDb in Spring Batch

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing, spring-data-mongodb

In our application, we implemented Spring Data MongoDB transactions by following this guide
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-transactions

However, we keep facing this issue.
I am unsure on how I should override the BatchConfigurer.

I have tried to follow this guide, but it uses an earlier version of Spring Data MongoDb. Some of the classes are deprecated
https://dzone.com/articles/spring-batch-goodies-with-mongodb

Error:

```
Description:

The bean 'transactionManager', defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [com/pragnamic/common/infrastructure/MongoDbConfig.class] and overriding is disabled.

Action:

Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

MongoDbConfig

```
@Configuration
public class MongoDbConfig extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {

    private final List<Converter<?,?>> converters = new ArrayList<>();

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.uri}")
    private String uri;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.database}")
    private String database;

    @Bean
    MongoTransactionManager transactionManager(MongoDatabaseFactory mongoDatabaseFactory) {
        return new MongoTransactionManager(mongoDatabaseFactory);
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return database;
    }

    @Override
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
         ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString(uri);
         MongoClientSettings mongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .applyConnectionString(connectionString)
                .build();
        return MongoClients.create(mongoClientSettings);
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoCustomConversions customConversions() {
        converters.add(new DomainObjectIdWriterConverter());
        return new MongoCustomConversions(converters);
    }

}
```

We are also using the latest version of Spring Data MongoDB

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Do you have `@EnableBatchProcessing` on one of your configuration classes? If it is the case, then you are facing https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/816. Please share your Spring Batch configuration to be able to help you.